# SVG rectangles pushed together in Firefox but not Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, css, animation, firefox, svg

I've got an SVG that I've animated. It works fine (or at least as well as it needs to for now), however when I look at it in Firefox, the 2nd and 3rd rectangles of the SVG are squashed together.

No idea why, as it's fine in Chrome/Safari. I think it may be something to do with the `transform: scaleY`, but not 100% sure.

If anyone can tell me why/how to fix, that'd be great.

Sidenote: If anyone knows how to sort the smoothness when it stops/starts, awesome, but that may be another question.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Will5592/pen/WPQQKB

```js
const svg = document.querySelectorAll('rect');

svg.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    svg.forEach(i => i.classList.toggle('animation-on'))
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animation-on {
  animation: updown 0.75s infinite linear;
}

rect {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: scaleY(0.75);
}

rect:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0.05s;
}

rect:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.075s;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
}

rect:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.10s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

rect:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 0.125s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

rect:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
  animation-duration: 0.85s;
}

@keyframes updown {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14 17.5">
  
  <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:purple;stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:indigo;stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <rect fill="url(#grad1)" rx="2px" ry="1px" x="2.86" y="4" width="2.57" height="9.5"/>
      <rect fill="url(#grad1)" rx="2px" ry="1px"x="8.57" y="1.85" width="2.57" height="13.81"/>
      <rect fill="url(#grad1)" rx="2px" ry="1px"x="11.43" y="5.18" width="2.57" height="7.14"/>
      <rect fill="url(#grad1)" rx="2px" ry="1px"y="6.13" width="2.57" height="5.24"/>
      <rect fill="url(#grad1)" rx="2px" ry="1px"x="5.71" width="2.57" height="17.5"/>
    </g>
  </g>  
</svg>
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Firefox.

Comment: I see ok, thanks. I'll have to think of an alternative then.

Comment: Reported this bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1523343

Comment: You can avoid this bug by using whole numbers for the `x` coordinate (see bug report for an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above. Using whole numbers for the `x` coordinate seems to be a workaround for this issue.

In the example below, I've multiplied all coordinate values by 10 and rounded off the `x` coordinate.

```js
const svg = document.querySelectorAll('rect');

svg.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    svg.forEach(i => i.classList.toggle('animation-on'))
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animation-on {
  animation: updown 0.75s infinite linear;
}

rect {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: scaleY(0.75);
}

rect:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0.05s;
}

rect:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.075s;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
}

rect:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.10s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

rect:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 0.125s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

rect:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
  animation-duration: 0.85s;
}

@keyframes updown {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 140 175">
  
  <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:purple;stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:indigo;stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <rect fill="url(#grad1)" rx="20px" ry="1px" x="29" y="40" width="25.7" height="95"/>
      <rect fill="url(#grad1)" rx="20px" ry="1px" x="86" y="18.5" width="25.7" height="138.1"/>
      <rect fill="url(#grad1)" rx="20px" ry="1px" x="114" y="51.8" width="25.7" height="71.4"/>
      <rect fill="url(#grad1)" rx="20px" ry="1px" y="61.3" width="25.7" height="52.4"/>
      <rect fill="url(#grad1)" rx="20px" ry="1px" x="57" width="25.7" height="175"/>
    </g>
  </g>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, that has indeed sorted out the problem and saved me a lot of headache!